# Render y-axis properly when overlaying pandas KDE and histogram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Similar questions to this have been asked before but not using these exact two plotting functions together so here we are:

I have a column from a pandas DataFrame that I am plotting both a histogram and the KDE. However, when I plot them, the y-axis is using the raw data value range instead of discrete number of samples/bin (what I want). How can I fix this? The actual plot is perfect, but the y-axis is wrong.

Data:

```
t2 = [140547476703.0, 113395471484.0, 158360225172.0, 105497674121.0, 186457736557.0, 153705359063.0, 36826568371.0, 200653068740.0, 190761317478.0, 126529980843.0, 98776029557.0, 132773701862.0, 14780432449.0, 167507656251.0, 121353262386.0, 136377019007.0, 134190768743.0, 218619462126.0, 07912778721.0, 215628911255.0, 147024833865.0, 94136343562.0, 135685803096.0, 165901502129.0, 45476074790.0, 125195690010.0, 113910844263.0, 123134290987.0, 112028565305.0, 93448218430.0, 07341012378.0, 93146854494.0, 132958913610.0, 102326700019.0, 196826471714.0, 122045354980.0, 76591131961.0, 134694468251.0, 120212625727.0, 108456858852.0, 106363042112.0, 193367024628.0, 39578667378.0, 178075400604.0, 155513974664.0, 132834624567.0, 137336282646.0, 125379267464.0]
```

Code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
# plot hist + kde
t2[t2.columns[0]].plot.kde(color = "maroon", label = "_nolegend_")
t2[t2.columns[0]].plot.hist(density = True, edgecolor = "grey", color = "tomato", title = t2.columns[0])

# plot mean/stdev
m = t2[t2.columns[0]].mean()
stdev = t2[t2.columns[0]].std()
plt.axvline(m, color = "black", ymax = 0.05, label = "mean")
plt.axvline(m-2*stdev, color = "black", ymax = 0.05, linestyle = ":", label = "+/- 2*Stdev")
plt.axvline(m+2*stdev, color = "black", ymax = 0.05, linestyle = ":")
plt.legend()
```

What it looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Is seaborn an option? [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) with `kde=True` would probably make this simpler.

Comment: Maybe for the next plotting I'll use seaborn. I'm trying not to add more modules to the environment and since pandas.DataFrame's have their own plotting functions I'd like to use those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the real counts, the you'll need to scale the KDE up by the width of the bins multiplied by the number of observations. The trickiest part is accessing the data pandas uses to plot the KDE. (I've removed parts related to the legend to simplify the problem at hand).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Calculate KDE, get data
axis = t2[t2.columns[0]].plot.kde(color = "maroon", label = "_nolegend_")
xdata = axis.get_children()[0]._x
ydata = axis.get_children()[0]._y
plt.clf()


# Real figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
# Plot Histogram, no density.
x = ax.hist(t2[t2.columns[0]], edgecolor = "grey", color = "tomato")

# size of the bins * N obs
scale = np.diff(x[1])[0]*len(t2)

# Plot scaled KDE
ax.plot(xdata, ydata*scale, color='blue')
ax.set_ylabel('N observations')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful thank you! Quick question, why did you use subplots if you're overlaying? I thought you use subplots to put plots side-by-side.

Comment: @ninthpower - `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` is the normal [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html) approach.

Comment: @ALollz So I keep getting an error: `AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no attribute '_x'.` Debugger is pointing to `xdata = axis.get_children()[0]._x`

Comment: weirdly, when I plot to a pdf, it still plots this (and the other 20+ plots) just fine. I think it may be related to when the column I'm working from has values very close together (e.g. [1.003, 1.0029, 1.001...])

Comment: @ninthpower hmm, the Line2D object might be in a different position for your `axis`. There's probably a better way to select it instead of just based on position, but you can print(axis) just after that plot and see which index contains the Line2D object to get the values